# Wrong display name is propagated in Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, identity-management, oim

We have Active directory connector installed on OIM 11gR2 PS3. We have configured the connector to populate display name as "First Last" in Pre-Populate as well as in Change task.

But when we tried to provision the AD account to user,
the displayName is coming as "Last Middle First" in target AD.

We check the Full Name at process form which is mapped to displayName from AD is coming properly as per requirement i.e First Last. I am not getting why the displayName is not coming properly in target.

Comment: check the target name generation policy if there is any

Comment: So can we say there is nothing to do with OIM, something is going wrong on AD target?

Comment: I had checked both OIM as well as AD target name generation policies those are configured as "First Last" only.

Comment: If we change the Full name mapping to other string variable from AD then the value is being populated is correct. There is no any issue with it.

Comment: can you explain more so does that string has 3 token as last middle and first? and still its working fine?

Comment: @ Chaitanya
I have added two mapping for Full Name in provisioning lookup, i.e. Full Name is mapped to displayName and other entenssionAttribute from AD. So when user created in OIM the Full Name is populated as "first last" but on AD displayName is coming as "last first Middle" and extensionAttribute coming as "first last".